# Multiple enqueueActions

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning, javascript-controller

Is it possible to have multiple enqueueActions? I know you can nest them as posted on this website https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000kKDRIA2. However, I would like to have enqueueAction1 fired and once that is done then call another method from server side (apex class) then fire that action as shown below.

```
test: function(component) {
    var eg = 'hello';
    var action = component.get("c.apexmethod1");
    action1.setParams({
        eg1: eg
        //ect
    });

    // set call back 
    action1.setCallback(this, function(response) {
       //do stuff
    });
    // enqueue the action 
    $A.enqueueAction(action1);

  //NOW HAVE ANOTHER CALL BACK AND ENQUEUE THAT ACTION

    var eg3 = 'hello';
    var action2 = component.get("c.apexmethod2");
    action2.setParams({
        eg2: eg3
        //ect
    });

    // set call back 
    action2.setCallback(this, function(responses) {
       //do stuff
    });
    // enqueue the action 
    $A.enqueueAction(action2);
 //IS THIS SECOND PART LEGAL?
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple actions queued at once. They will all be sent at the same time, unless too many are queued, in which case they will be processed in batches.